# Cauchy-Goursat Theorem vs Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

What is the difference between Cauchy Goursat Theorem and Cauchy Integral formula? Given an integral where you're supposed to use one of the two I can't seem to differentiate between them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Roughtly speaking,

Cauchy-Goursat apply only when the function is analytic both in the curve and its (geometric) interior.

Cauchy Integral Formula allows a (single) singularity inside the curve.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy-Goursat theorem is used to evaluate the contour integral of a holomorphic function f over the closed path C (which is an open subset of the range of f), and it states that such a contour integral equals 0: $$\oint_C f(z) dz = 0$$

Note: since f is holomorphic, it is complex differentiable everywhere inside the path C, and therefore has no singularities interior to C.

The Cauchy Integral Formula is used to evaluate the contour integral of a function on the closed path C, but now that the function can have a singularity at a single point $z_0$ interior to U. $$f(z_0)=\frac 1 {2\pi i} \oint_C \frac {f(z)} {z-z_0} dz$$